# How to get the relative file path of this file heirarchy in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Alpha

```
    c1
        source.js
    c2
        d
            e
                f
                    target
```

i want to get the relative path of target in the import statement of the source file

Comment: Have you tried? `../c2/d/e/f/target`

Comment: yes, uncaughtException: Cannot find module occurs

Answer (score 0):

`import '../c2/d/e/f/target';`

../ stands for one directory up

./ stands for in the same directory

Comment: yes, I tried this out and still i get uncaughtException: Cannot find module